# Stuck with a parsing error in PhpStorm

Tags: php, html

I've been stuck with an unexpected parsing error on PhpStorm for hours and hours on end and it's driving me mad!

[image]

The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and I can't figure out what that means.

### So far, I've tried

- Republishing the solution
- Clearing cache, cookies (*as suggested somewhere*)
- Wrapping the html in `echo '...'` (*didn't work; same problem*)

## Problem

I have a slight inkling as to what is happening but I'm not sure. The `<` symbol fails to parse at the very first line. Help!

> Actually, I'm trying to use an image slider. And this happened after I tried to port a working html static website to PHP. I'm guessing the images are all unformatted due to the same error?

## Snippet Sample

```html
<?php
define('SITE_PATH', ConstantModel::getDetailByName('site_path')->constant_value);
define('SITE_NAME', ConstantModel::getDetailByName('site_name')->constant_value);
define('CSS_PATH', SITE_PATH . 'includes/client/css/');
define('FONT_PATH', SITE_PATH . 'includes/client/font-awesome/');
define('JS_PATH', SITE_PATH . 'includes/client/js/');
define('IMAGE_PATH', SITE_PATH . 'includes/client/images/');
define('UPLOAD_IMAGE_PATH', SITE_PATH . 'uploads/');
define('CALENDAR', SITE_PATH . 'includes/client/calendar-master/');
define('MENU_PROGRAM_ID', '166');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    @include('layout.client.head')

    <script>var sitePath = '<?php echo SITE_PATH;?>';
</script>
</head>

<body>

@include('layout.client.header')
@yield('content')
{{--<!-- FOOTER -->--}}
@include('layout.client.footer')

@include('layout.client.foot')
</body>
</html>
```

home.blade.php

```html
@extends('layout.client.container')
@section('content')

<!--Slider-->  

<!--Slider-->
<div id="wrapper">
  
</div>
<!--Slider-->
<section >
  <div class="slider1-area overlay-default">
    <div class="bend niceties preview-1">
      <ul>
          <?php
          $banners = BannerModel::getHomePageBanners('2');
          $count = 1;
          if(count($banners) > 0) {
          foreach($banners as $banner) {
          ?>
        <li>
          <div id="ensign-nivoslider-3" class="slides">
              <?php if(file_exists('uploads/banners/' . $banner->banner_attachment) && $banner->banner_attachment != ''){ ?>
            <img  src="<?php echo $sitePath . 'uploads/banners/' . $banner->banner_attachment;?>" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg">
              <?php } ?>
            @if($banner->banner_caption)
          </div>
          <div id="slider-direction-1" class="t-cn slider-direction">
            <div class="slider-content s-tb slide-1">
              <div class="title-container s-tb-c">
                <h1 class="title1">{{$banner->banner_caption}}</h1>
                @endif
                @if($banner->banner_description)
                  <p>{{$banner->banner_description}} </p>
                  <div class="slider-btn-area"> <a href="#" class="default-big-btn">Read More</a> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endif
        </li>
          <?php $count++; }} ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
  <div class="courses1-area">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="title-default-left">News & Events</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="rc-carousel"
                        data-loop="true"
                        data-items="3"
                        data-margin="30"
                        data-autoplay="true"
                        data-autoplay-timeout="10000"
                        data-smart-speed="2000"
                        data-dots="false"
                        data-nav="true"
                        data-nav-speed="false"
                        data-r-x-small="1"
                        data-r-x-small-nav="true"
                        data-r-x-small-dots="false"
                        data-r-x-medium="2"
                        data-r-x-medium-nav="true"
                        data-r-x-medium-dots="false"
                        data-r-small="2"
                        data-r-small-nav="true"
                        data-r-small-dots="false"
                        data-r-medium="3"
                        data-r-medium-nav="true"
                        data-r-medium-dots="false"
                        data-r-large="3"
                        data-r-large-nav="true"
                        data-r-large-dots="false">
             <?php $eventLists = NewsModel::getAllActiveEventsForHome();
             if(count($eventLists) > 0){
             foreach($eventLists as $singleEvent){
             ?>
        <div class="courses-box1">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="courses-img-wrapper hvr-bounce-to-bottom"> 
                                    <?php if(file_exists('uploads/news/' . $singleEvent->news_attachment) && $singleEvent->news_attachment != '') { ?>
                                    <img src="{{$sitePath}}uploads/news/{{$singleEvent->news_attachment}}"
                                         alt="{{ $singleEvent->news_heading}}" class="img-responsive"/>
                                    <?php }
                                    else{?>
                                    <img alt="{{ $singleEvent->news_heading}}"
                                         src="{{ asset('includes/client/images/noimage.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive"
                                         />
                                    <?php } ?>
                                 <a href="{{ route('news', $singleEvent->news_url)}}"></a>
            <div class="courses-content-wrapper"> 
                   <ul >
                    <li> - {{ date("M", strtotime($singleEvent->news_date)); }}
                                    {{ date("d", strtotime($singleEvent->news_date)); }},
                                    {{date("Y", strtotime($singleEvent->news_date));}}</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p>{{$singleEvent->news_short_description}}</p> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          <?php }} ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>  
<!--ABout US-->
<!-- Management Team -->
<section>
    <div class="lecturers-area">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="title-default-left">Founder</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="rc-carousel"
                        data-loop="true"
                        data-items="4"
                        data-margin="30"
                        data-autoplay="true"
                        data-autoplay-timeout="10000"
                        data-smart-speed="2000"
                        data-dots="false"
                        data-nav="true"
                        data-nav-speed="false"
                        data-r-x-small="1"
                        data-r-x-small-nav="true"
                        data-r-x-small-dots="false"
                        data-r-x-medium="2"
                        data-r-x-medium-nav="true"
                        data-r-x-medium-dots="false"
                        data-r-small="3"
                        data-r-small-nav="true"
                        data-r-small-dots="false"
                        data-r-medium="4"
                        data-r-medium-nav="true"
                        data-r-medium-dots="false"
                        data-r-large="4"
                        data-r-large-nav="true"
                        data-r-large-dots="false">
              <?php $management_teams = MessageModel::getAllMessages();
             if (count($management_teams) > 0) { ?>
             @foreach($management_teams as $management_team)
        <div class="single-item">
          <div class="lecturers1-item-wrapper">
            <div class="lecturers-img-wrapper"> 
              <?php if(file_exists('uploads/pages/'. $management_team->photo) && $management_team->photo != ''){ ?>
              <img  src="<?php echo $sitePath . 'uploads/pages/' .$management_team->photo;?>" class="img-responsive">
                  <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="lecturers-content-wrapper">
              <h3 class="item-title">{{ $management_team->name}}</h3>
              <p class="item-title">{{ $management_team->title}}</p>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         @endforeach
          <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--ABout US-->
<!-- ------------photo gallary--------- -->
<div class="news-event-area">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="title-default-left">Photo Gallery</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="rc-carousel"
                        data-loop="true"
                        data-items="3"
                        data-margin="30"
                        data-autoplay="true"
                        data-autoplay-timeout="10000"
                        data-smart-speed="2000"
                        data-dots="false"
                        data-nav="true"
                        data-nav-speed="false"
                        data-r-x-small="1"
                        data-r-x-small-nav="true"
                        data-r-x-small-dots="false"
                        data-r-x-medium="2"
                        data-r-x-medium-nav="true"
                        data-r-x-medium-dots="false"
                        data-r-small="2"
                        data-r-small-nav="true"
                        data-r-small-dots="false"
                        data-r-medium="3"
                        data-r-medium-nav="true"
                        data-r-medium-dots="false"
                        data-r-large="3"
                        data-r-large-nav="true"
                        data-r-large-dots="false">
                 <?php $albums = AlbumModel::getAllAlbums();
             if (count($albums) > 0) { ?>
             @foreach($albums as $album)
        <div class="courses-box1">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="courses-img-wrapper hvr-bounce-to-bottom"> 
                <?php if(file_exists('uploads/albums/'. $album->album_attachment) && $album->album_attachment != ''){ ?>
                  <img  src="<?php echo $sitePath . 'uploads/albums/' .$album->album_attachment;?>" class="img-responsive"  alt="news">
                  <?php } ?>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="courses-content-wrapper">
                   <h3 class="title"> <a  href="{{ route('album', $album->album_url)}}">{{ $album->album_title }}</a></h3>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         @endforeach
          <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Students Say Area Start Here -->
  <div class="students-say-area">
    <h2 class="title-default-center">What Our Students Say</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="rc-carousel"
                        data-loop="true"
                        data-items="2"
                        data-margin="30"
                        data-autoplay="true"
                        data-autoplay-timeout="10000"
                        data-smart-speed="2000"
                        data-dots="true"
                        data-nav="false"
                        data-nav-speed="false"
                        data-r-x-small="1"
                        data-r-x-small-nav="false"
                        data-r-x-small-dots="true"
                        data-r-x-medium="2"
                        data-r-x-medium-nav="false"
                        data-r-x-medium-dots="true"
                        data-r-small="2"
                        data-r-small-nav="false"
                        data-r-small-dots="true"
                        data-r-medium="2"
                        data-r-medium-nav="false"
                        data-r-medium-dots="true"
                        data-r-large="2"
                        data-r-large-nav="false"
                        data-r-large-dots="true">
        <div class="single-item">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="profile-img-wrapper"> 
              <a href="#" class="profile-img"><img class="profile-img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ asset('includes/client/images/profile1.png') }}" alt="Testimonial"></a> 
            </div>
            
          <p></p>
            <div class="tlp-tm-content-wrapper">
              <h3 class="item-title"><a href="#">Rosy Janner</a></h3>
              <span class="item-designation">Grade 10 Student</span>
              <div class="item-content">I am very happy with my choice of Puspasadan College. This college is what I expected to be . All teachers are well experiencd and friendly. I also liked available facilities.  Oxbridge International College is all about expressing your personality shades and accepting those of others: shades of friendship and fraternity; of sports stars and scholars; of learners and leaders...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single-item">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="profile-img-wrapper"> <a href="#" class="profile-img"><img class="profile-img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ asset('includes/client/images/profile1.png') }}" alt="Testimonial"></a> </div>
            <div class="tlp-tm-content-wrapper">
              <h3 class="item-title"><a href="#">Dainel Dina</a></h3>
              <span class="item-designation">Ex-Student</span>
              <div class="item-content">I am very happy with my choice of Puspasadan College. This college is what I expected to be . All teachers are well experiencd and friendly. I also liked available facilities.  Puspasadan College is all about expressing your personality shades and accepting those of others: shades of friendship and fraternity; of sports stars and scholars; of learners and leaders...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single-item">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="profile-img-wrapper"> <a href="#" class="profile-img"><img class="profile-img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ asset('includes/client/images/profile1.png') }}" alt="Testimonial"></a> </div>
            <div class="tlp-tm-content-wrapper">
              <h3 class="item-title"><a href="#">Rosy Janner</a></h3>
              <span class="item-designation">Ex-Student</span>
              <div class="item-content">I am very happy with my choice of Puspasadan College. This college is what I expected to be . All teachers are well experiencd and friendly. I also liked available facilities.  Puspasadan College is all about expressing your personality shades and accepting those of others: shades of friendship and fraternity; of sports stars and scholars; of learners and leaders...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single-item">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="profile-img-wrapper"> <a href="#" class="profile-img"><img class="profile-img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ asset('includes/client/images/profile1.png') }}" alt="Testimonial"></a> </div>
            <div class="tlp-tm-content-wrapper">
              <h3 class="item-title"><a href="#">Dainel Dina</a></h3>
              <span class="item-designation">Grade 10 Student</span>
              <div class="item-content">I am very happy with my choice of Puspasadan College. This college is what I expected to be . All teachers are well experiencd and friendly. I also liked available facilities.  Puspasadan College is all about expressing your personality shades and accepting those of others: shades of friendship and fraternity; of sports stars and scholars; of learners and leaders...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single-item">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="profile-img-wrapper"> <a href="#" class="profile-img"><img class="profile-img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ asset('includes/client/images/profile1.png') }}" alt="Testimonial"></a> </div>
            <div class="tlp-tm-content-wrapper">
              <h3 class="item-title"><a href="#">Rosy Janner</a></h3>
              <span class="item-designation">Grade 10 Student</span>
              <div class="item-content">I am very happy with my choice of Puspasadan College. This college is what I expected to be . All teachers are well experiencd and friendly. I also liked available facilities.  Oxbridge International College is all about expressing your personality shades and accepting those of others: shades of friendship and fraternity; of sports stars and scholars; of learners and leaders...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single-item">
          <div class="single-item-wrapper">
            <div class="profile-img-wrapper"> <a href="#" class="profile-img"><img class="profile-img-responsive img-circle" src="{{ asset('includes/client/images/profile1.png') }}" alt="Testimonial"></a> </div>
            <div class="tlp-tm-content-wrapper">
              <h3 class="item-title"><a href="#">Dainel Dina</a></h3>
              <span class="item-designation">Ex-Student</span>
              <div class="item-content">I am very happy with my choice of Puspasadan College. This college is what I expected to be . All teachers are well experiencd and friendly. I also liked available facilities.  Puspasadan College is all about expressing your personality shades and accepting those of others: shades of friendship and fraternity; of sports stars and scholars; of learners and leaders...</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Students Say Area End Here -->     
@endsection
```

Comment: The syntax error showing in the browser console would appear to be a Javascript syntax error, not PHP.  Also, it's complaining about the file `404`, not `home`.  Check the network console for the content-type of the 404 file.  It should be text/html.  Also, the newline before your doctype should be deleted.  Very well written question.  Thank you.

Comment: In your image - too much website and not enough console message area

Comment: Well formatted question but, as others have pointed out, I'd like to see the complete console message as well. Please update your question.

Comment: **1)** It looks like it complaints for `404` file and not actual home page. **2)** You would need to provide actual final HTML of the page -- no way to see the error from the screenshot and that code sample **3)** I have removed `phpstorm` tag as it has nothing to do with actual PhpStorm -- the error description is misleading as error is not shown in PhpStorm but in actual browser in final generated HTML.

Comment: Most likely you're referencing some external Javascript file which doesn't exist and results in a 404 HTML error page, which is not valid Javascript, hence the error. As everybody else said: check your network tab.